# UILabel font switches back after unselecting text

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uilabel

I have a problem: I want to change the font in my UILabel. When I select the text in the UILabel and I change the font it works, but when I unselect the text, the font comes back to defaut.

Someone have an idea?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing it in interface builder? It is very straight forward though. You can also do that using code.

```
lblName.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

`labelName.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];` or any other font style can be assigned as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 18.0 ];
textLabel.font  = myFont;
```

This should change the font, however Are you changing it in IB?  Also it depends on the type of font you are selecting. It may not be visible in IB and rendering on device depends on the fonts available on it.